# TypeError: Cannot read property 'toUpperCase' of undefined on *ngif - ionic 4

Tags: ionic4

I try to use *ngif and else to pass a false to boolean.The ngif is working but the else keep get the error above.  Hope some will help me.

```
  <div *ngFor="let nameList of nameList">
     <ion-row class="cont-text" *ngIf="nameList?.alertType ==='new'; else let this.havedata === 'false'">
        &#8226; {{nameList?.description}} from {{NameList?.creationDate | date : 'dd MMM yyyy'}}<br>
     </ion-row>
  </div>
   <div *ngIf="haveData === 'false'">
       <ion-row class="cont-text">No Problem is captured</ion-row>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only use the else block as a 'pointer' to a  element with a specified label:

```html
<div *ngIf="condition; else elseBlock">Content to render when condition is true.</div>
<ng-template #elseBlock>Content to render when condition is false.</ng-template>
```

Read more about it in the documentation: https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf

---

You could fix your implementation by segregating your data before you display it to the html page. You could loop over the items in the ts file and fill the correct array and/or error variables. Or use the correct else approach:

```html
<div *ngFor="let nameList of nameList">
  <ion-row class="cont-text" *ngIf="nameList?.alertType ==='new'; else #elseBlock">
    &#8226; {{ nameList?.description }} from {{ NameList?.creationDate | date : 'dd MMM yyyy' }}<br>
  </ion-row>
</div>
<ng-template #elseBlock>
  <ion-row class="cont-text">No Problem is captured</ion-row>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: I have follow the suggestion given, but  result is not correct. For example, the array data has 4 record, it will display  2 new record and 2 of the message.  Is there a way to display stop display the message when there new alertType and when there none it is only display once time.